# React change route by change component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have an application using react, redux,react-router v3, react-router-redux.
I want to implement a search page with multi attributes. How can I write an actioncreator for onChange event of an input component.
For example when I checked a checkbox, url must go to mysite.com/search?checkbox1=checked. without any refresh. thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read the help section on how to ask a question

Answer (score 0):

You can you the `push` method to redirect to another route.

```js
import { routeActions } from 'react-router-redux'

 function MyComponent({ dispatch }) {
   return <Button onClick={() => dispatch(routeActions.push('/foo'))}/>;
}
```

From oficial documentation v3 (https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux/tree/3.0.x)